# react-scroll does not work in Electron app

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-scroll

Why animateScroll from react-scroll package doesn't work in my electron App?
ScrollBounce set to true for BrowserWindow, here the component

```
import { css, cx } from "emotion";
import { animateScroll  } from "react-scroll";
import {
  ChatModel,
} from "domain/index";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { messageMapSelector } from "redux-layer/selectors";
import Message from "components/content-message";

const ChatView = ({ className, chat }) => {
  const messageMap = useSelector(messageMapSelector);

  useEffect(() => {
    animateScroll.scrollToBottom({
      containerId: "ContainerElementID"
    });
  }, [chat]);

  return (
    <div id="ContainerElementID">
      {chat.id
        ? (messageMap.get(chat.id) || []).map((message) => (
            <Message
              data={message}
              key={message.id}
            />
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatView;
```

Expected behavior: chat view should scroll down to the last message after chat populated or new messages come

Actual behavior: nothing happen when chat property updated and animateScroll.scrollToBottom fired in use effect

Comment: what is the actual behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @tpikachu , I updated description, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should to move this implementation for another component

```
animateScroll.scrollToBottom({
      containerId: "ContainerElementID"
});
```

Because you trying to add scroll for `window(global)` now instead of to add scroll for parent element which has your scrollbar in app, so you have issues with use `window.scroll` and `animateScroll`.

Add this scroll method for parent element of `"ContaierElementID"` should solve your issue